# React & Ant Design - Submit form before switching tabs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an ant design tab group with an ant design form in each tab. I would like that upon switching tabs, the user is prompted to submit their changes. If the user selects yes, then the data should be submitted. We switch tabs only if the response comes back as a success, or the user opted not to save.

The forms are all child components, which means the parent needs to somehow indicate that the tab is switching, and tell the child to submit their form.

I can achieve this with the `useImperativeHandle` hook and `forwardRef` but I'm wondering if there is some non-imperative way to achieve this?

Here is a stripped down example, not checking if the form is dirty, and just using the native confirm popup. There is also an async function to simulate submitting the form, which will randomly succeed or error.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zw2cgi?file=my-form.tsx

The forms:

```
export type FormRef = { submit: (data?: Data) => Promise<boolean> };

export type Data = { someField: string };

const MyForm = (props: {}, ref: Ref<FormRef>) => {
  const [form] = useForm<Data>();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ submit }));

  async function submit(data?: Data): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!data) data = form.getFieldsValue();
    const res = await submitData(data);
    return res;
  }

  return (
    <Form form={form} onFinish={submit}>
      <Form.Item name="someField">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(MyForm);
```

The parent component with the tabs:

```
const App: FC = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState('tabOne');
  const formOneRef = useRef<FormRef>();
  const formTwoRef = useRef<FormRef>();

  async function onChange(key: string) {
    if (confirm('Save Changes?')) {
      if (activeKey === 'tabOne' && (await formOneRef.current.submit()))
        setActiveKey(key);
      if (activeKey === 'tabTwo' && (await formTwoRef.current.submit()))
        setActiveKey(key);
    } else setActiveKey(key);
  }

  const tabs = [
    {
      label: 'Tab One',
      key: 'tabOne',
      children: <MyForm ref={formOneRef} />,
    },
    {
      label: 'Tab Two',
      key: 'tabTwo',
      children: <MyForm ref={formTwoRef} />,
    },
  ];

  return <Tabs items={tabs} onChange={onChange} activeKey={activeKey} />;
};
```

The submit function

```js
export default async function submitData(data: Data) {
  console.log('Submitting...', data);
  const res = await new Promise<boolean>((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(
      () => (Math.random() < 0.5 ? resolve(true) : resolve(false)),
      1000
    )
  );
  if (res) {
    console.log('Success!', data);
    return true;
  }
  if (!res) {
    console.error('Fake Error', data);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Ant Design Tabs: https://ant.design/components/tabs/

Ant Design Form: https://ant.design/components/form/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a state variable to store the submit function, and setting it in the child with `useEffect`.

A few caveats:

Had to set `destroyInactiveTabPane` to ensure forms were unmounted and remounted when navigating, so `useEffect` was called.

Had to wrap the form's `submit` function in `useCallback` as it was now a dependency of `useEffect`.

Had to make sure when calling `setSubmitForm` I had passed a function that returns the function, else the dispatch just calls submit immediately.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-n8y3kh?file=App.tsx

```
export type Data = { someField: string };

type Props = {
  setSubmitForm: Dispatch<SetStateAction<() => Promise<boolean>>>;
};

const MyForm: FC<Props> = ({ setSubmitForm }) => {
  const [form] = useForm<Data>();

  const submit = useCallback(
    async (data?: Data): Promise<boolean> => {
      if (!data) data = form.getFieldsValue();
      const res = await submitData(data);
      return res;
    },
    [form]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setSubmitForm(() => submit);
  }, [setSubmitForm, submit]);

  return (
    <Form form={form} onFinish={submit}>
      <Form.Item name="someField">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

```
const App: FC = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState('tabOne');
  const [submitForm, setSubmitForm] = useState<() => Promise<boolean>>(
    async () => true
  );

  async function onChange(key: string) {
    if (confirm('Save Changes?')) {
      if (await submitForm()) setActiveKey(key);
    } else setActiveKey(key);
  }

  const tabs = [
    {
      label: 'Tab One',
      key: 'tabOne',
      children: <MyForm setSubmitForm={setSubmitForm} />,
    },
    {
      label: 'Tab Two',
      key: 'tabTwo',
      children: <MyForm setSubmitForm={setSubmitForm} />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Tabs
      items={tabs}
      onChange={onChange}
      activeKey={activeKey}
      destroyInactiveTabPane
    />
  );
};
```